# jquery animate when distance from bottom is equal to variable

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, offset

I am having a little trouble with a scroll animation.

I first wrote the jQuery with a mistake in mind: if i animate an object when it gets to a certain distance from the top of the page, that will get me into big trouble on devices with different screen sizes.

So, what i would like to do is, instead of measuring the distance to the top, measure the distance to the bottom of the viewport. This would allow me to start animation as soon as the elements is let's say 100px from the bottom, no matter which screen size.

But for some silly reason i'm not getting there...   =(

Here is the code i have now:

```
var doc = $(document);

$(".feature").each(function(){
    // VARIABLES
    var feature = $(this);
    var featureOffset = feature.offset().top-400;

    // ANIMATE FUNCTION
    doc.on("scroll", function(){
        if ( doc.scrollTop() > featureOffset && feature.hasClass("abouthidden") ) {
            feature.removeClass("abouthidden");
        }
        if ( doc.scrollTop() < featureOffset && feature.not("abouthidden") ) {
            feature.addClass("abouthidden");
        }
    });
});
```

I know i am making a "thinking mistake", but i can't find it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: use  var featureOffset = ($(window).height() - feature.offset().top); this will give you exact position of element on screen

Comment: but how do i then measure to distance to the bottom of the viewport?

Comment: use $(document).height() . it will give you total height of page. so when you have total height and element top position you can deduct top position of element form height . so it will give you distance from bottom

Comment: Thanks, that did it!!!
How can i give you some "+" or vote up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code . $(window).height() it will give you total height of window. so when you have total height and element top position you can deduct top position of element form height . so it will give you distance from bottom

```
  var featureOffset = ($(window).height() - feature.offset().top);
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Nishit Maheta (THANKS!!) i ended up using the $(window).height()

Here is the code working like i wanted

```
var doc = $(document);

$(".feature").each(function(){
    // VARIABLES
    var feature = $(this);
    var featureOffset = feature.offset().top;
    var windowheight = $(window).height();

    // 200 is the distance from the bottom at which the animation actually starts 
    // could have used a variable
    var startAnimation = featureOffset - windowheight + 200; 

    // ANIMATE FUNCTION
    doc.on("scroll", function(){
        if ( doc.scrollTop() > startAnimation && feature.hasClass("abouthidden") ) {
            feature.removeClass("abouthidden");
        }
        if ( doc.scrollTop() < startAnimation && feature.not("abouthidden") ) {
            feature.addClass("abouthidden");
        }
    });
});
```